# WebView filling entire parent

Tags: android, webview

I want to load some content in a `DialogFragment` using a `WebView`. The following is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/decline"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:letterSpacing="0.1"
            android:text="DECLINE"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/app_theme"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/accept"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/proceed_button"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:letterSpacing="0.1"
            android:text="ACCEPT"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is inasmuchas the height of the webview is set to wrap_content and the buttons are placed below the webview in the relative layout container, the buttons are only visible before the content actually loads. Afterwards, they are completely hidden.

How can i show both the buttons and the webview in the dialog without either obstructing the other?

Comment: using `LinearLayout` might help you.

Comment: Try using a LinearLayout as the root view and setting the layout_weight of the webview to 1.

Comment: I tried that out first before switching to a `RelativeLayout` but the result was the same.

Comment: or align `LinearLayout` (which contains Button) to bottom and set `WebView` above that layout.

Comment: @vrundpurohit that worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, try this layout.

Align `LinearLayout` (which contains Button) to bottom and set `WebView` above that layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"

        android:layout_above="@+id/myLayout" 

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 

        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/decline"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:letterSpacing="0.1"
            android:text="DECLINE"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/app_theme"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/accept"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/proceed_button"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:letterSpacing="0.1"
            android:text="ACCEPT"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```